# Integrity constraint violation error in Magento 2.1.2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to edit configurable product and getting error. I am using Magento version 2.1.2

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Go to admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Google API section
2. Change the configuration Enable Content Experiments to "Yes"
3. Save a configurable product and its child product consecutively.

**Expected result:**

1. Product should be save successfully with any number of times.

**Actual result:**

1. failed to save product
2. getting bellow error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '0-402-product' for key
>   'GOOGLEOPTIMIZER_CODE_STORE_ID_ENTITY_ID_ENTITY_TYPE', query was:
>   UPDATE googleoptimizer_code SET entity_id = ? WHERE (code_id='136')

Anyone can help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. To fix this issue I edit configurations options and its worked for me. please refer this link http://prntscr.com/e7px78